# jQuery slideToggle nested ul

Tags: jquery, nested, html-lists, slidetoggle

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sqeq/MCtL9/2/)

I recently changed my markup and since then my jQuery toggle function isn't working anymore. I tried to handle this but I got a few requirements I just don't know how to solve.

Here is what I want to achieve:

1. clicking on Link 1 or 2 slideToggles its ul (with Sublink 1 etc)
2. clicking on Sublink 1 or 2 slideToggle its ul (with Snippet 1 etc.)
3. clicking on any closed element, it should CLOSE any other open element. Means when Link 2 is open and I click on Link 1, Link 2 should close. When Sublink 2 is open and I click on Sublink 1, Sublink 2 should close. And important: when Sublink 1 under Link 1 is open, I click on Link 2 and then again on Link 1, Sublink 1 should be closed and not still left open
4. clicking twice on the same element shouldn't toggle in and out at the same time
5. it should be possible to have e.g. Link x, Sublink x AND Snippet x with the class "active", so that one knows where exactly he is (active = other backgroundcolor). So my toggleClass isn't that correct..

In order to be able to change the appearance of the list elements, you have to change the display mode from `none` to `block`

```
$("#sidebar-left .submenu-ebene2").css('display', 'block');
$("#sidebar-left .submenu-ebene3").css('display', 'none');
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you for taking your time!

Here is the jQuery:

```
$("#sidebar-left .submenu-ebene2").css('display', 'none');
  $("#sidebar-left .submenu-ebene3").css('display', 'none');
    $("ul > li.closed").click(function (e) {
      if (e.target === this) {
          $(this).siblings("li.open").find(" > ul").slideToggle('fast', function () {
              $(this).parents("li.open:first").toggleClass("open closed");
          });

          $(this).toggleClass("closed open").find(" > ul").slideToggle('fast');
      }
});

$(".link").click(function(e) {
    $(".active").toggleClass("inactive active");
    $(this).addClass("active").removeClass("inactive");
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sqeq/MCtL9/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
$("li").click(function (e) {
       $(this).next("li").children(".submenu-ebene2").stop().slideToggle();
});
$(".submenu-ebene2 li").click(function() {
    $(this).next("li").children(".submenu-ebene3").stop().slideToggle();
});

$(".link").click(function(e) {
    $(".active").toggleClass("inactive active");
    $(this).addClass("active").removeClass("inactive");
});
```

Also, hide .submenu-ebene2 with css

```
.submenu-ebene2 {
    display: none;
}
.submenu-ebene3 {
 display: none;   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/defmetalhead/pLv77/2/

Comment: Well this solves one of my problems. But I cant see the other ones to work with it. Anyways, I try to work with it. Thank you for that!

Comment: Updated the fiddle and code. Now works for submenu. Understand that the HTML is horrid and I added a class to the first UL.